# WordPress TwentyTen Theme Incompatible with Theme Unit Test

Tags: themes, comments, theme-twenty-ten

I'm trying to test the comments template on a theme that is based on TwentyTen, using the the WP Theme Unit Test XML file, and there is one post that does not display comments properly.

The post is called "Comment Test", and it contains 20 comments, including 2 pingbacks. The only thing that displays are the pingbacks. Is that the expected behavior? I can't seem to figure out why it's only displaying the pingbacks. Perhaps there is a setting I missed in the backend.

The way to reproduce this, is to create a blog, apply the TwentyTen theme, and import the WP Theme Unit Test file: http://svn.automattic.com/wpcom-themes/demo/test-data.2011-01-17.xml

Then visit the post called "Comment Test", published on March 3, 2008. You should see it say "20 Responses to Comment Test", and underneath it you should see 2 pingbacks, no comments.

Thanks for you help,
Dave

Comment: http://cdn.rvoodoo.com/03/comment-test/ works for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Twenty Ten has been [tested by the theme review team](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/439) and it passes all the unit tests.**

You can see how it looks on one of the [demo test installs](http://demo.wordpressthemesshare.com/2008/03/comment-test/) or another [install I found](http://fightshorts.info/2008/03/comment-test/).

Try doing a fresh install of WordPress with a new database with no plugins.

Comment: Ah, I see. There must be something going on with my configuration. I'll try deactivating some plugins. Thanks so much for your help.